# Private data liveliness settings in a hyperledger fabric private data collection

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

Currently, collections_config.json file (a private data collection feature in Hyperledger Fabric) only allows to set up data liveliness to be based on the amount of blocks which needs to be reached before it gets deleted from the private data collection.

Are you aware of any other ways to speed this process up or control it more efficiently? For instance, by setting a date or an occurrence of an attribute written in a public part of the ledger that would trigger private data deletion?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To delete the private data from the private state database on collection members, you can call DelPrivateData() in chaincode. To completely purge the private data from the block storage data structure however, you must wait for the number of blocks specified in the block-to-live policy (there is no common system time across peers, and therefore it cannot be time-based).